# Why does mobile site have excessive white space to the right?

Tags: html, css

Have a site that in the mobile version that has excessive space to the right on iPhone. The site is www.liveinhomecare.com

Had fix previously that worked by using overflow: hidden; but not working anymore.

Anyone know of a way to fix this?

btw I have full-width banners for text that is probably causing this but using the above fix corrected this, but now it is back...

```
.banner h1 {
    clear: both;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    text-transform: uppercase !important; 
    color: #ebebeb !important;

    font-size: 12px !important; 
    font-size: 0.75rem !important; 
    line-height: 1.25;
    margin-top: 0.250em;
    margin-bottom: 0em;
}
.banner h2{
    margin-top: 0.750em !important; 
    color: #ffffff !important;
}

.banner {
    position: relative; /* for child pseudo-element */
    z-index: 0;
    margin: 0 -600rem;
    /* add back negative margin value */
    padding: 0.25rem 600rem;
    background: #3887b7;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;

    overflow: hidden;
}
.banner:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1; /* behind parent */
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    /* subtract h2 padding (1.5rem) */
    left: 598.5rem;
    right: 598.5rem;
    background: #3887b7;

    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Need your HTML too. A [mcve]

Comment: Why does your banner have a -600 horizontal margin and a 600 horizontal padding.

Comment: It maybe smart to share your code via a "JSFiddle" here is the link. https://jsfiddle.net/.
When you share via that platform other developers can look and change your code and share their changes.

Comment: @Kjvhout Not necessary. Users can create runnable snippets in their question here just like on jsfiddle

Comment: Nothing wrong on your site

Comment: Hm, site doesnt load anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add overflow-x: hidden; to your HTML element:

```
    html {
      height: 100%;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: You got it. Can you please mark it as the correct answer so people know this has been solved?